# In an Intent Architect template, can I resolve a type (from a string) so it will include appropriate using statements?

Tags: c#, .net-core, intent-architect

In a template which generates code dynamically based on certain conditions, some of the code uses types which require additional using statements to compile correctly. How do I reference/use such a type such that the using will be included in the generated output iff that specific code is generated?

e.g. Given this code, how would I make sure the correct using is added?

```
if (attribute.IsEnum()) {
    // Resolve the EnumToStringConverter type?
    statements.Add($".HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<{attribute.Type.Element.Name}>());");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `UseType(...)` method that is available on the `CSharpTemplateBase` base class (available in `Intent.Modules.Common.CSharp.3.0.10` nuget package).

For example, you could try something like this:

```cs
if (attribute.IsEnum()) {
    // Resolve the EnumToStringConverter type?
    statements.Add($".HasConversion(new {UseType("EnumToStringConverter", "<your-required-namespace>"}<{attribute.Type.Element.Name}>());");
}
```

There is also another overload which would take in the fully qualified name. For example:
`UseType("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.EnumToStringConverter")`

(assuming you're using the `EnumToStringConverter` from EF Core)